# How to OCR a text with white colour characters on a blue background from a cropped image?

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, python-tesseract

First, I want to crop an image using a mouse event, and then print the text inside the cropped image. I tried OCR scripts but all can't work for this image attached below. I think the reason is that the text has white characters on blue background.

Can you help me with doing this?

Full image:

[image: The full image:]

Cropped image:

[image]

An example what I tried is:

```
import pytesseract
import cv2
import numpy as np

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'

img = cv2.imread('D:/frame/time 0_03_.jpg')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
adaptiveThresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 35, 30)
inverted_bin=cv2.bitwise_not(adaptiveThresh)

#Some noise reduction
kernel = np.ones((2,2),np.uint8)
processed_img = cv2.erode(inverted_bin, kernel, iterations = 1)
processed_img = cv2.dilate(processed_img, kernel, iterations = 1)
 
#Applying image_to_string method
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(processed_img)
 
print(text)
```

Comment: have you tried converting the image to b/w?

Comment: Yes here : cv2.bitwise_not(adaptiveThresh)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[EDIT]**

For anyone wondering, the image in the question was updated after posting my answer. That was the original image:

[image: Input 1]

Thus, the below output in my original answer.

That's the newly posted image:

[image: Input 2]

The specific Turkish characters, especially in the last word, are still not properly detected (since I still can't use `lang='tur'` right now), but at least the `Ö` and `Ü` can be detected using `lang='deu'`, which I have installed:

```py
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(mask, lang='deu').strip().replace('\n', '').replace('\f', '')
print(text)
# GÖKYÜZÜ AVCILARI ILE TEKE TEK KLASIGI
```

**[/EDIT]**

---

I wouldn't use `cv2.adaptiveThreshold` here, but simple `cv2.threshold` using `cv2.THRESH_OTSU + cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV`. Since, the comma touches the image border, I'd add another, one pixel wide border via `cv2.copyMakeBorder` to capture the comma properly. So, that would be the full code (replacing `\f` is due to my `pytesseract` version only):

```py
import cv2
import pytesseract

img = cv2.imread('n7nET.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
mask = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU + cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]
mask = cv2.copyMakeBorder(mask, 1, 1, 1, 1, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, 0)
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(mask).strip().replace('\n', '').replace('\f', '')
print(text)
# 2020'DE SALGINI BILDILER, YA 2021'DE?
```

The output seems correct to me – of course, not for this special (I assume Turkish) capital I character with the dot above. Unfortunately, I can't run `pytesseract.image_to_string(..., lang='tur')`, since it's simply not installed. Maybe, have a look at that to get the proper characters here as well.

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:        3.9.1
PyCharm:       2021.1.1
OpenCV:        4.5.1
pytesseract:   5.0.0-alpha.20201127
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: I put the wrong crop image. Now I fixed it. Could you check your answer?

Comment: @fyec I already edited my answer before your notification, please re-check.